# UK tourist visa?

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, tourist-visas

How difficult it is to get a UK tourist visa?. I am indian national holding EU residence permit. I checked the home office website, it seems they take 3 weeks to give a visa (they take the passport), plus about 185 pounds fee. Outrageous!

Can i go to Scotland and Ireland with the UK visa? i have no plans to stay in UK for more than 2 weeks.

Comment: Ireland is not part of the UK...Scotland is.

Comment: What do you mean by 'how difficult'? If you fill out the paperwork correctly and pay the money, and haven't committed any crimes..it's fairly straightforward.

Comment: Scotland is part of the UK as is Northern Ireland. The Republic of Ireland is not part of the UK, but you can visit on a UK tourist visa.  You can use the expedite service to improve turn-around time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How difficult is it to apply? Or how difficult is it to be approved?

The application is fairly simple, just read all the [requirements](https://www.gov.uk/general-visit-visa/documents-you-must-provide), submit the documents and wait. While the official advice is that visas take up to three weeks (and longer in some circumstances) actually most are processed much faster -- applying in Mumbai the turnaround time is [2 days](https://visa-processingtimes.homeoffice.gov.uk/y/mumbai-india/all). It may take longer if they have to send your passport to the nearest clearing office. As for the cost a six month 'general visit' visa has an [83GBP](https://www.gov.uk/general-visit-visa/overview) fee, which compares favorably to a UK citizen applying for an Indian visa where you'll pay 82 + 10.20 = [92.20GBP](http://in.vfsglobal.co.uk/touristvisa_fees.html).

I don't know where you're getting your information from, but I'm not sure you're looking in the right place or at the correct visa.

Of course, none of that guarantees you'll be approved. All you can do is make the best case that you a) intend to stay for no longer than the visa conditions allow (i.e. have a return ticket and/or proof that you have employment, study or family commitments in India that you need to return to) and b) you can support yourself for your trip (i.e. show you have enough money in a bank account, or someone willing to provide the money such as family or friends somewhere). The more evidence you can show to support these two points the better chance you have of being approved. I've heard that proof that you have traveled previously and returned home may help, although it's not something that's spelled out on the website. Also explain why you want to go to the UK, what you want to do there, etc.

I'd refrain from using the same tone as this post ('Outrageous!') in any application.

As the comments say, Scotland and Northern Ireland are part of the UK and covered by the visa. The Republic or Ireland is not *however* as you are an Indian citizen you can take advantage of the [British Irish Visa Scheme](http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/British%20Irish%20Visa%20Scheme), the key point:

> The Minister for Justice and Equality, Frances Fitzgerald, T.D., announced on 16th June, 2014 that the ‘British Irish Visa Scheme’ between Ireland and the United Kingdom will commence this Autumn starting with China and India.
>
> The British Irish Visa Scheme will allow for travel to and around the Common Travel Area (CTA) on a single visa. As matters stand, many overseas tourists and business visitors who wish to visit both Ireland and the UK, including Northern Ireland, need separate Irish and UK visas.
>
> From the Autumn the objective is that visitors from China and India will be able to travel freely within the Common Travel Area using either an Irish or UK visa. This will mean that tourists, business visitors etc. will be able, for the first time, to visit both Ireland and the UK, including Northern Ireland, on a single visa.

This also means you can investigate the costs and requirements of an [Irish visa](https://www.dfa.ie/travel/visas/visas-for-ireland/) and apply for that instead, but still visit the rest of the UK. It is actually a bit cheaper, and there are some more visa options.

Finally, just for completeness, I'll note that even having a visa does not guarantee that immigration will let you enter either country. The border control agents still have the ultimate right to refuse entry or ask further questions at the border.

Comment: The OP is applying from Budapest.

Comment: @GayotFow, was that edited out of the question, where did you get Budapest from? In any case application times in Budapest are between 10 and 15 working days so up to three weeks, but not definitely three weeks. Visa fee is still the same. https://visa-processingtimes.homeoffice.gov.uk/y/budapest-hungary/all and https://visa-fees.homeoffice.gov.uk/y/hungary/eur/visit/general-visitors/short-term-up-to-6-months-single-or-multiple-entry

Comment: I checked his profile

Comment: In Budapest they they 180 pound general fee. Hmmm

Comment: Update: visa refused from Warsaw. i forgot attaching some company documents, and they think i am going to UK for taking up employment. Unbelievable :(